# Change windows border on Gnome 3 on CentOS 7?

Tags: linux, centos, gnome, themes

I've downloaded new GTK3 themes and installed to the .theme folder, I can see that I can select the new theme under Gtk+ theme in Tweak tool, but it doesn't change the border.

I can see that Current theme in Tweak tool changes the border, but I can't select the new theme from there.

So how would one go about changing the border given by new themes in CentOS 7 with Gnome 3?

Example new theme that contains border but not picked up by Tweak tool: http://gnome-look.org/content/show.php/Aurora

Answer (score 0):

[image: Enable User Themes in Gnome-Tweak-Tools]

Enable the User Themes and see if that changes.